# JSON Array Ordering based on Origin and Destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects

I have a JSON array as below I want to order my JSON array as A-B, B-C, C-D, D-E! I am trying to achieve the below-mentioned output! My values are actually flight origin-destination! for example ATL-DXB, DXB-MIA, MIA-MAA ! So there is no D-A scenario! I want to order it in a way that if the starting point is given as ATL then the ordering should be starting with ATL-DXB!

```
     function compare(a, b) {
              if (b.origin != a.destination) return 1;

              return 0;
            }
            const jsonArray =  const jsonArray = [
 {
            "origin": "MAA",
            "destination": "AVG"
          },
 {
            "origin": "ATL",
            "destination": "MIA"
          },{
            "origin": "DXB",
            "destination": "MAA"
          }, {
            "origin": "MIA",
            "destination": "DXB"
          }        ];
             var result = jsonArray.sort(compare);
```

output I got:

```
  [
    { origin: 'MAA', destination: 'AVG' },
    { origin: 'ATL', destination: 'MIA' },
    { origin: 'DXB', destination: 'MAA' },
    { origin: 'MIA', destination: 'DXB' }
  ]
```

output I want

```
 [
    { origin: 'ATL', destination: 'MIA' },
    { origin: 'MIA', destination: 'DXB' },
    { origin: 'DXB', destination: 'MAA' },
    { origin: 'MAA', destination: 'AVG' }

  ]
```

Comment: Question: Will your values always be in that sequence? Is it possible to have `A-C`, `D-A`? If yes, how do you want it handled?

Comment: My values are actually flight origin-destination! for example ATL-DXB, DXB-MIA, MIA-MAA ! So there is no D-A scenario! I want to order it in a way that if starting point is given as ATL then the ordering should be starting with ATL-DXB! Hope this makes sense? @AlgefAlmocera

Comment: `return a.origin.localeCompare(b.origin) || a.destination.localeCompare(b.destination)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to find the path between the first origin and the the last destination.

If I am right you need two stage.
Firstly, find your top node and then reorder your nodes according to this.

This solution is not possibly the most effective one but this is the first thing I thought.

```js
const jsonArray = [{
            "origin": "MAA",
            "destination": "AVG"
          },
 {
            "origin": "ATL",
            "destination": "MIA"
          },{
            "origin": "DXB",
            "destination": "MAA"
          }, {
            "origin": "MIA",
            "destination": "DXB"
          }];

console.log(sortXY(jsonArray));

function findTop(array) {
  let top = array[0];
  while (true) {
    let temp = array.find(a => a.destination == top.origin);
    if (!temp) {
      break;
    } else {
      top = temp;
    }
  }
  return top;
}

function sortXY(array) {
  let top = findTop(array);
  let newArray = [];
  newArray.push(top);
  while (true) {
    let temp = array.find(a => a.origin == top.destination);
    if (!temp) {
      break;
    } else {
      newArray.push(temp);
      top = temp;
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE since the question was changed:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.destination == b.origin) return -1;
  if (a.origin == b.destination) return 1;
  return 0;
}
const jsonArray = [{
  "origin": "ATL",
  "destination": "MIA"
}, {
  "origin": "MIA",
  "destination": "DXB"
}, {
  "origin": "DXB",
  "destination": "MAA"
}];
var result = jsonArray.sort(compare);

console.log(result);
```

---

In this case you can compare first by origin, then if origin is the same you compare by destination.

However, by reading your updated comments, looks like comparing origins only is enough in your case :)

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  let originDiff = a.origin.localeCompare(b.origin);
  return originDiff == 0 ? a.destination.localeCompare(b.destination) : originDiff
}
const jsonArray = [{
  "origin": "C",
  "destination": "D"
}, {
  "origin": "A",
  "destination": "B"
}, {
  "origin": "D",
  "destination": "E"
}, {
  "origin": "B",
  "destination": "C"
}];
var result = jsonArray.sort(compare);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I took alphabets as an Example! This solution is not working for this JSON
 const jsonArray = [{
            "origin": "ATL",
            "destination": "MIA"
          },{
            "origin": "DXB",
            "destination": "MAA"
          }, {
            "origin": "MIA",
            "destination": "DXB"
          }
         ];

Comment: Then it's a lot different. Please update your answer with all the new details, input and expected output. My solution works on your current question, if the question changes, it's obvious that the answer might need an update.

Comment: I have updated the question with updated details please have a look at it

Comment: Done, have a look

Comment: It is only working for three segments! if I add more than three its failing